# What part of my python program is leading to errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
irounddigits = int(input('how many digits you want to round to'))
stype = input('do you have a float(f) or a fraction(dp)(please select one)')

if stype == "f":
    rtoberounded = float(input('enter the number your want to round'))
    print (round(rtoberounded[`irounddigits]))

else:
    inumerator = int(input(' what is your numerator(integer please)'))
    idemoninator = int(input(' what is your demoninaotr(integer please)'))
    ffinalnumber = inumerator / idemoninator
    rnumber = (round(ffinalnumber[irounddigits]))
    print (rnumber)
```

that's my code, but I keep getting errors like 
`TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`
 I've tried searching up what that error means but none of the answers seem to apply to my code

Answer (score 0):

this part

```
round(rtoberounded[irounddigits])
```

and this part

```
round(ffinalnumber[irounddigits])
```

`rtoberounded` and `ffinalnumber` is a float, you can't call it  like an array/list.

I think you misundertsood the `[, ndigits]` part in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round). It means optional argument.

Comment: I really wish they'd use normal argument notation when it's representable as a normal Python function (no C built-in weirdness violating the normal rules for Python level function signatures), e.g. `round(number, ndigits=0)`. The `[, ndigits]` notation should really only be used when there is no "placeholder" value (the C level function detects presence or absence, so there is no value to pass to mean "no argument"), and/or the optional param is positional only (can't be passed by keyword). Neither case applies here, yet they still used the non-standard signature. Sigh...

Comment: I agree, I was also confused at first

Answer (score 0):

[round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) takes the two parameters (**number** and **number of digits**) separated by comma `,`:

> **round**(*number*[, *ndigits*])
>   Return *number* rounded to *ndigits* precision after the decimal point.

Change to:

```
round(rtoberounded, irounddigits))
```

and

```
rnumber = (round(ffinalnumber, irounddigits))
```